# Could not find file dacpac?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, publish, database-project

When I try to publish a database project, while Creating Publish Preview..., I get this error: Could not find file 'C:...[DatabaseProjName]\sql\debug[DatabaseProjName].dacpac'.
How do I get this file?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I was getting this error over and over and could not figure out why.  I would get the latest, overwrite existing files, checked all of my publish connection info, checked the database project properties, still got the error.

The cause, maybe due to a bug, I don't know, but neither building my solution nor publishing the database project was actually building the database project.

The **solution** is simple, just right-click on the database project and Rebuild.  This will create the dacpac file and allow you to publish.

Comment: Wow couldn't believe it was that easy. Thanks a lot

Comment: Rebuilding database project worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: The solution is really helpful, please mark it as helpful

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your installed version of SQL where are you trying to deploy is the same than the project properties.